# What foreshadowing was Corey Feldman's character referring to in Dream A Little Dream?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, dream-a-little-dream

There's a scene in [1989's Dream A Little Dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_a_Little_Dream) where Jason Robards' character is talking to Corey Feldman's character "telepathically" via a dream.  He's done this a number of times previously, but this time he's asking what he needs to do or something, and at one point Corey Feldman's character says to him something like, "If you had just paid attention 4 dreams ago, you'd already know!"

I know this is a longshot, but does anyone know specifically if Feldman's character **did** say something foreshadowing, and if so can you point me to the specific point in the film where he says it?

Comment: Regarding your tag wiki edits (and in light of people probably not correctly rejecting them): http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/752/49.